# Nested template class syntax error (MSVC)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and having some issues with a function returning a nested template class inside a template outer class. I have made a minimal example, the real one involves a lot more code:

```
template<typename R, typename... S>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    class Bar
    {

    };
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename... S>
typename Foo<R, S...>::Bar<T> fooBar() { // <--- LINE 33

}
```

This yields a whole set of errors (mostly from subsequent code):

- 33: error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
- 33: error C2059: syntax error : '<'

And it also affects subsequent code, tons of syntax error come for all the lines afterwards.

Am I not seeing something or could this be an issue of Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM/SOLUTION**

You are required to use the keyword `template` in this context to tell the compiler that `Bar` is indeed a template, as in the below snippet:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename... S>
typename Foo<R, S...>::template Bar<T> fooBar() { // <--- LINE 33
   ...
}
```

---

**BUT WHY?**

We are required to use the `template` keyword whenever a *template name* is a *dependent template name*, without it the compiler will treat `Bar` in `Foo<R, S...>::Bar` as a *non-template*, which doesn't make sense; and it errors.

Further reading:

- [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1090079)

Comment: I think you should add the line `return typename Foo<R, S...>::template Bar<T>();` in the function to complete the example.

Comment: @RSahu We don't know if `Bar<T>` is *default constructible*, instead I've added `...` to the example to show that the contents of the function is left out (by intention).